# Gentoo Installation on Virtualbox, startx fails

Tags: installation, virtualbox, xorg, gentoo

I followed the Gentoo [`Linux x86 Quick Installation Guide`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gentoo-x86-quickinstall.xml) the base system is installed on virtualbox. I want gnome in it. The docs say I need to install `hal`. But `emerge` says `there are no ebuilds to satisfy "hal"`. I did `eselect profile list` and then did `eselect profile set 4` which is `[4]   default/linux/x86/10.0/desktop/gnome` as this [forum post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-811651-postdays-0-postorder-asc-start-0.html) says. Then I did 
`emerge -e system` which took several hours and downloaded lots of files. after that I did a restart and `startx` fails, even `Xorg -configure` fails. saying

```
(EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to to load module/driver vmwgfx
(EE) vmware: Unexpected failure while loading the "vmwlegacy" driver. Giving up.
(EE) Failed to load module "vmware" (a required submodule could not be loaded, -1077713160)
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
```

I am very new to gentoo. and I cannot understand where should I move now.

Answer (score 2):

Where do the docs say you need to install hal? Admittedly that quick guide mentions hal in the USE flags but that's all. hal is now obsolete and should be totally avoided.

Did you install xf86-video-vmware? This is the video driver you need for X.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I was getting confused because the error mentioned VMware even though you're running under VirtualBox. You should remove xf86-video-vmware and emerge virtualbox-guest-additions, which will pull in xf86-video-virtualbox. See [this wiki page](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Virtualbox_Guest) for more information.

Comment: even emerged `app-emulation/open-vm-tools` with no luck

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on wiki describing this http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox

Look at part "Linux Guests"

Answer (score 0):

```
# eix xf86-video -S virtual 
* x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox
     Available versions:  4.1.4 ~4.1.6-r1 ~4.1.8 {dri kernel_linux}
     Homepage:            http://www.virtualbox.org/
     Description:         VirtualBox video driver

# emerge x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox 
 * Last emerge --sync was Wed Jan 11 10:35:01 2012.
>>> Verifying ebuild manifests
>>> Starting parallel fetch
>>> Emerging (1 of 5) sys-devel/bin86-0.16.17
>>> Installing (1 of 5) sys-devel/bin86-0.16.17
>>> Emerging (2 of 5) sys-power/iasl-20090123
>>> Installing (2 of 5) sys-power/iasl-20090123
>>> Emerging (3 of 5) sys-devel/dev86-0.16.17-r6
>>> Installing (3 of 5) sys-devel/dev86-0.16.17-r6
>>> Emerging (4 of 5) dev-util/kbuild-0.1.9998_pre20110817
>>> Installing (4 of 5) dev-util/kbuild-0.1.9998_pre20110817
>>> Emerging (5 of 5) x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.4
>>> Installing (5 of 5) x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.4
>>> Recording x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox in "world" favorites file...

 * Messages for package x11-drivers/xf86-video-virtualbox-4.1.4:

 * You need to edit the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf and set:
 * 
 *   Driver  "vboxvideo"
 * 
 * in the Graphics device section (Section "Device")
 * 
 * To use the kernel drm video driver, please add:
 * "vboxvideo" to:
 * /etc/conf.d/modules
 * 
vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf (or some other text editor)

  Section "Device"
       Identifier     "Fake card"
       Driver         "vboxvideo"
       VendorName     "VirtualBox"
       BoardName      "Fake board"
   EndSection

Section "Screen"

   # Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
   # Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
   # Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP: 1680x1050_60 +0+0"
       Identifier     "BottomDisplay"
       Device         "Fake card"
 (...)
```

## save the file. run startx